# How do you refer to someone whose title has changed?

Tags: etiquette, titles

I am writing a personal statement for a PhD application and I’d like to refer to my previous lecturer.  He was a Dr. at the time he taught me but he is now a professor at another institution.

Is there a neat way of referring to someone like this or do I have to go with something clumsy as:

> I was taught by Dr. X (now Prof.) on his course about Y.

Comment: A title refers to a person, not to the time you have met that person, you can use Professor X.

Comment: Has X's doctorate been rescinded? (Is that even possible?)

Comment: At least in some schools in the United States, "Professor" is used to indicate a faculty member who doesn't hold a doctorate, so maybe be a little careful. Also, you get rid of a lot of clum when you dump the passive voice.  "Dr. X, now professor of high-energy magic at... inspired me when..."

Comment: @200_success:  Yes, doctorates can be rescinded.  A search for "doctorate rescinded" finds several.  One has to have screwed up pretty badly, though.

Answer (score 9):

The person is now a professor, so refer to them primarily as that.  If you are concerned about confusion, you can add the additional information in the sub-clause, where it reads more smoothly:

> I took course Y from Prof. X, while he was a [lecturer, postdoc, whatever] at [instutition]"